# How to dynamically load data to a sapui5 table and bar graph using data binding

Tags: javascript, sapui5

My html

```
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="content1"></div>
    <div id="content2"></div>

</body>
```

My Js

```
    var myData= {
            user:[{id:"1",firstname:"x",lastname:"k"},
                  {id:"2",firstname:"y",lastname:"k"},
                  {id:"3",firstname:"z",lastname:"k"}],
            expense:[{expenseno:"1",uid:"1",item:"c",amount:"1500"},
                     {expenseno:"2",uid:"2",item:"t",amount:"1150"},
                     {expenseno:"3",uid:"3",item:"p",amount:"500"},
                     {expenseno:"4",uid:"1",item:"y",amount:"1000"},
                     {expenseno:"5",uid:"2",item:"t",amount:"3500"},
                     {expenseno:"6",uid:"3",item:"s",amount:"3500"},
                     {expenseno:"7",uid:"1",item:"q",amount:"900"}],

    };
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(myData);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
    // user table
    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.DataTable({
        title : "Users",
        width : "100%",
        visibleRowCount : 3,
        selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
        editable : false
    });
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "User ID"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"{id}"})
    }));
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "First Name"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"{firstname}"})
    }));
    oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Last Name"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"{lastname}"})
    }));
    oTable.bindRows("/user");
    oTable.placeAt("content");


    // expense table
    var oTable2 = new sap.ui.table.DataTable({
        title : "Expense",
        width : "100%",
        visibleRowCount : 5,
        selectionMode : sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
        editable : false
    });

    oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "User Id"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"{uid}"})
    }));

    oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Expense No"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"{expenseno}"})
    }));

    oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Items"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"{item}"})
    }));

    oTable2.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label: new sap.ui.commons.Label({text: "Amount"}),
        template: new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value:"{amount}"})
    }));
    oTable2.bindRows("/expense");
    oTable2.placeAt("content1");

    // bar graph
    var dataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions : [ {
            axis : 1,
            name :"Item",
            value : "{item}"
        }],

        measures : [ {
            name :"Amount",
            value : "{amount}"
        } ],

        data : {
            path : "/expense",
            //filters : how to filter on the basis of row selected on first table,
        }
    });

    var column = new sap.viz.ui5.Column({
        width : "95%",
        height : "400px",
        showLegend : false,
        plotArea : {
        //'colorPalette' : d3.scale.category20().range()
        },
        title : {
            visible : true,
            text : "Item vs Amount"
        },
        dataset : dataset
    });
    column.placeAt("content2");


    oTable.attachRowSelect(function(oEvent){
        // get the binding context of the first selected row
        var selectedRowContext = oEvent.getParameter("rowContext");
        var selectedUserId = oModel.getProperty("id", selectedRowContext);

            // filter expenses
            var listBinding = oTable2.getBinding();
            var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("uid", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, selectedUserId);
            listBinding.filter([oFilter]);

            // how to filter graph                  
    });
```

What I did so far:

- Created two tables and one bar graph. if I select one row form my
  first table(user), second table(expense) got updated on the basis of
  User Id selected.[using attachRowSelect(function(oEvent)- code help
  from sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com]

Now I want to update the bar graph also on the basis of User Id selected on first table. Say if I select row 1(user id 1), bar graph should only show the items and amounts associated with user id 1 from expense data set.

Thank you, Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I didn't got your requirement completely. Based on your understanding the following may help to you.

```
        var datasetBinding = dataset.getBinding("data");
        var oFilter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter("uid", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, selectedUserId);
        datasetBinding.filter([oFilter2]);
```

Comment: Hi Sarath, it's my bad, your code is working fine. Thanks alot